# Protecting PDF file with password in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, pdf, plsql, pdf-generation

I need to ecrypt PDF file with password in Oracle Database 12c.

I have PDFs in BLOB column in database and I want to write function that returns BLOB which contains encrypted PDF.

Then if I save that pdf to disk and open it with Acrobat Reader I want to be prompt for password.

In most simple scenerio (which will be fine for now) I need something like this:

```
FUNCTION Encrypt_Pdf(
    pdf_ IN BLOB,
    password_ IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN BLOB
IS
    encrypted_pdf_ BLOB;
BEGIN
    -- do something with pdf_ to encrypt it with password_


    RETURN encrypted_pdf_;
END Encrypt_Pdf;
```

I've looked for some free packages but I found only pl/pdf which is commercial :( other free solutions for PDFs in PL/SQL dont provide encryption (as_pdf3, pl_fpdf).

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: you can use a for example  [PL/PDF](https://www.plpdf.com/)

Comment: PL/PDF is commercial for 600$, I want something free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I’ve found solution. I’ve loaded java library iText into database and wrote java package which encrypt and returns pdf as oracle.sql.BLOB then I’ve called it from plsql and it worked well.